# Is it possible to calculate how many minutes ago something was added in the database?

Tags: mysql

Right now I have one table that has one column named `timestamp`, it's data type and default values are: `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

This works just fine, and I can automatically save the current time.

I want to add a new column to the table using a select query that calculates how many minutes ago it was added.

Let's say its `Fri 0:14` right now and on `Fri 0:10` a new row was added. I want the new column to say: `5 minutes ago`.

If the row was added over `1 hour ago` I want to change the format to: `07-04-2017 on 23:00`.

Is there anyway to accomplish this result?

Comment: Don't do this in the database, this is more of an application-level problem.

Comment: So is there a way to just calculate it in minutes? Like 500 min ago from now? Just saving the 500 as a value. The same way I should calculate the age. @Rogue

Comment: I suppose it's better to compute the field because that can be inferred using `created_at` timestamp and current timestamp, rather than storing in the table itself.